# Zoom in many UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextview

I have many UITextView and UIImageView inside UIScrollView.
This UITextViews and UIImageView I create dynamic.
How can I put zoom in and zoom out if this elements I create dynamic? Sometimes I have one UITextView and one UIImageView, sometimes I have two UIImageViews and one UITextView and etc...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to figure out the contentSize for the UIScrollView. Loop through all of the UIViews added and determine the one in the lowest-right corner then grab it's frame origin + size and that should be the full size then set the scrollview.contentSize to that CGSize value.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a view (either `UIView` or a subclass of `UIView`) with everything you would like to zoom in on on it and return it in the `UIScrollView`'s `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` delegate method.

Obviously set the `contentSize`, `maximumZoomScale` and `minimumZoomScale` properties accordingly.